# Making new columns of keys with values stores as a list of values from a list of dicts?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (10 million rows) which looks like following. For better understanding, I have simplified it.

```
user_id     event_params
10          [{'key': 'x', 'value': '1'}, {'key': 'y', 'value': '3'}, {'key': 'z', 'value': '4'}]
11          [{'key': 'y', 'value': '5'}, {'key': 'z', 'value': '9'}]
12          [{'key': 'a', 'value': '5'}]
```

I want to make new columns that are all the unique keys from the dataframe, with values stored in the respective keys. Output should like below:

```
user_id x   y   z   a
10      1   3   4   NA
11      NA  5   9   NA
12      NA  NA  NA  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create the new dataframe and append new lines via [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) function. You can find more alternatives [here](https://thispointer.com/python-pandas-how-to-add-rows-in-a-dataframe-using-dataframe-append-loc-iloc/).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

data = [
    [12, [{'key': 'x', 'value': '1'}, {'key': 'y', 'value': '3'}, {'key': 'z', 'value': '4'}]],
    [13, [{'key': 'a', 'value': '5'}]]
]

for user_id, event_params in data:
    record = {e['key']: e['value'] for e in event_params}
    record['user_id'] = user_id
    df = df.append(record, ignore_index=True)

df
```

[image]

Comment: You copy-pasted the whole my code into Jupyter notebook? What version of Python do you have? I just checked this code in Python3, and it works good.

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-50530ee286b8> in <module>
      1 d = pd.DataFrame()
      2 
----> 3 for user_id, event_params in df:
      4     record = {e['key']: e['value'] for e in event_params}
      5     record['user_id'] = user_id

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: below is the first column value:

[{'key': 'firebase_screen_class', 'value': 'MainViewController'},
 {'key': 'firebase_event_origin', 'value': 'auto'},
 {'key': 'firebase_screen_id', 'value': '2899526371368326565'},
 {'key': 'engagement_time_msec', 'value': '3441'}]

Comment: You are trying to run my code over your data. You haven't defined its format here. Of course it causes errors. I think the source of error is in difference between my data format and yours. For every record I have a list with two values - `key` and `event_params`. You are trying to parse `event_params` as a list with two values. Change the `for` line to fit to your logic.